# Gridview vertical scrolling - Windows Store App

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am making a Windows Store App using C#. Is it possible to make the Gridview a vertical scrolling gridview instead of horizontal?

Comment: Use a listview instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you're not developing for Windows 10 UWP yet, as there it's vertical by default.

If you want a 'vertical scrolling GridView' with a single column, then use a `ListView` instead. If you want vertical scrolling with multiple columns, you can use following XAML:

```
<GridView
    ...
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto">

    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>

</GridView>
```

What you change from the default behavior is disabling horizontal scrolling and enabling vertical scrolling. Next to that you're telling the `WrapGrid` (or whatever container you're choosing to use) to place the items horizontally adjecent to each other and wrap to a new line vertically.